# Pandas groupby cumulative sum to threshold

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

Using a groupby operation in Pandas, can the cumsum function be used to meet (or exceed by one record) a threshold?

The Goal is to *at least meet or exceed* the threshold and then stop accumulating further.

**Example dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
{'a':'z', 'b': 5, 'c': 15}, {'a':'z', 'b': 10, 'c': 15},
'a':'z', 'b': 2, 'c': 15},
{'a': 'x', 'b': 10, 'c':31}, {'a':'x', 'b': 20, 'c': 31}, {'a':'x',
'b': 5, 'c': 31, {'a':'x', 'b': 9, 'c': 31}
] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df:

    a   b   c
0   z   5   15
1   z   10  15
2   z   2   15
3   x   10  31
4   x   20  31
5   x   5   31
6   x   9   31
```

The only equation I can visualize doesn't meet or exceed the threshold for the X group:

```
df[df.groupby(by='a')['b'].cumsum()<=df['c']] 

    a   b   c
0   z   5   15
1   z   10  15
3   x   10  31
4   x   20  31
```

It works for group z (ie, 5+10 = 15) but fails for group x b/c (ie, 10+20 < 31).

For group x, I need to meet (or exceed by one record) the value of 31. So the next record should also be accumulated (ie 10+20+5 >= 31 but note it stops accumulating any further (ie doesnt also take 9).

Is there a way to apply an accumulative operation that will meet, or exceed by a single record, a benchmark?

**Expected/Desired Outcome:**

```
    a   b   c
0   z   5   15
1   z   10  15
3   x   10  31
4   x   20  31
5   x   5   31
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: why row 5 is in your expected output?

Comment: @lostcode because 10+20=30 which is less than 31, so include next record of 5 resulting in 35 which is at least equal to or exceeds by only one record.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using `np.sign` -1 means less than , 0 means equal, 1 means greater

```
d={x : y for x , y in df.groupby(np.sign(df.groupby('a').b.cumsum()-df.c))}
d
Out[30]: 
{-1:    a   b   c
 0  z   5  15
 3  x  10  31
 4  x  20  31, 0:    a   b   c
 1  z  10  15, 1:    a  b   c
 2  z  2  15
 5  x  5  31}
```

To get `d[0], d[1],d[-1]`

Comment: As written, this appears to return all records instead of the subset of records meeting condition. Dont think i provided enough context in my original question. Added more details

Comment: @JacamoFinane this return the dict , you need to get the df by d[0] , d[1],d[-1]

Comment: Thank you. New here. This is a dataframe of millions of records and I am looking to return a dataframe meeting condition. Maybe cumsum doesn't work here since it accumulates records in a sorted order.